# Modal not clickable

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

**Here is what it looks like when I click it and it is not clickable it just have a color of black.**

[image]

**Here is what it should look like.**

[image]

**This for when I click Change Password**

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-muted waves-effect waves-dark pro-pic" 
          href="" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Account</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right user-dd animated">
                               
           <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" data-toggle="modal" data-placement="top"  href="#account_edit"><i class="ti-settings "></i> Change Password</a>
```

**This for the modal**

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="account_edit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    
                                    <div class="modal-body">

                                        <!-- ############## -->
                                        
                                        <form action="account_edit.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                        
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email</label>
                                                <input disabled="disabled" type="email" name="user_email"  value="<?php echo $row['user_email']; ?>" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="" required>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                                        
                                        <input type="password" name="password"  value="" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="" required>
                                         <input type="hidden" name="id"  value="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="" required>
                                            </div>
                                            
                                            
                                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success">
                                        </form>
                                        
                                        <!-- bodyyyyyyyyyyyy///// -->
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Close</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: see backdrop's `z-index` and then add `z-index` to modal (value must be greater that backdrop).  `<div class="modal fade" style="z-index: 9999">`.

Comment: @HamzaIftikhar Sorry for late response. But it still won't work.